# Couldnt connect to JMX remote with jconsole

Tags: java, linux, spring, jmx, spring-3

I developing under Spring3.1 standalone env.

I am trying to connect my application remotely via jconsole. 
It's working locally but when I deploy my application into the linux machine it gets time out.

I am using Daemon in order to run my environment.

this is what I add in the run.sh script:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6969 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
com.mypackage.daemon.FixDaemon
```

and inside applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:mbean-server />
<context:mbean-export />
```

now on the linux machine after doing netstat thats what we see:

```
[root@ logs]# netstat -an | grep 6969
tcp        0      0 :::6969                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

so it's seems like it does listening.

but when I add my ip:6969 inside the jconsole interface I get connection failed popup.

any idea what am I doing wrong?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First try to add also this option to your application:

`-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<ip>`

Also keep in mind jconsole is using RMI for the communication. This means jconsole first connects to ip:6969. Then server generates a random port X which is passed back to the jconsole. Jconsole then opens another connection to ip:X. Since X is random, there is no way you can open this specific port in the firewall. You have either to open all ports or use a socks proxy which is another subject.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try connecting to that port using telnet from your machine. If this does not succeed it usually is because of a firewall dropping packets. You will have to talk to your network administrator to open up that port.

   **Note**: You will have to open up two ports. One for binding the RMIRegistry and another one to export the RMI objects. RMI usually exports objects on random high ports. But this will not work in a firewall-ed environment hence you would have to configure the port on which it is exported. This is done by using a RMI URL.
2. If you are running this on Linux then do a `hostname -i`, if it returns 127.0.0.1 then fix `/etc/hosts`. [The FAQ entry for JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/faq.html#linux2) has more information on this.
3. Another option I would strongly suggest is to look at [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) which does not involve changing the firewall configuration but still provides the JMX goodies over HTTP.